# Unable to send a response while multipart form is being streamed

Tags: node.js, sails.js, multipartform-data

I'm using nodejs combined with sailsjs and skipper to upload files to a server.

I have a use case where I need to check the file length and send a 413 error if the upload exceeds A certain file size. However when I try send any kind of response nothing happens. What exactly is happening here? Does the form upload need to be completed before a response can be sent?

```
    var getReceiver = function () {
      var receiver = new Writable({objectMode: true});
      receiver._write = function (file, enc, done) {

        file.fd = directory + file.fd;

        var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(file.fd);

        fileStream.on('error', function (err) {
          done(err);
        }).once('finish', function () {
          done();
        });

        var fileLength = 0;
        file.on('data', function (chunk) {
          fileLength = fileLength + chunk.length;
          if (fileLength > maxFileSize) {
            var err = new Error('upload exceeds maxFileSize.');
            file.unpipe();
            fs.unlink(file.fd, function (fsErr) {
              if (fsErr && (typeof fsErr !== 'object' || fsErr.code !== 'ENOENT')) {
                return done([err].concat([fsErr]));
              }
            });
            return done(err);
          }
        });

        file.pipe(fileStream);
      };

      return receiver;
    };

    req.file('file').upload(getReceiver(), function (err, uploadedFiles) {
      if (err) {
        return res.badRequest(err);
      }

      // Do stuff

          }
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: It looks like you're in danger of calling `done` more than once, which is probably not helping the situation.  You should be more careful about that.  `done` is being called in 4 different places and I suspect that its possible for as many as all of them to run in the course of a single request.

Comment: ??? I'm not sure what you mean by this, the cb here is only called within event listeners.

Comment: Both the error and finish handlers can be called, and if the file length is too large, `done` gets called again there.  Finally, if unlinking the file fails, `done` gets called yet again.  It is very hard to reason about callback code if callbacks can be called multiple times.